# multiple ways to update javascript object using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

functional programming has introduced immutable, so es6's map is quite a popular approach when working with data, specifically in arrays and object.

I have a reducer of redux below

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO': {
            return state.map(todo => 
                todo.id !== action.id ? todo 
                : {
                ...todo, checked: !todo.checked
                }
            )
        }
        default:
           return state
    }

}
```

What's the alternative to change the checked property besides above approach? Is the code even readable at all?

someone prefer this

```
switch (action.type) {
        case "TOGGLE_TODO":
            return [
                ...state.slice(0, action.id),
                {...state[action.id], isCompleted: !state[action.id].isCompleted},
                ...state.slice(action.id + 1)
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

Comment: There are quite a couple of errors. The case is missing a `:` and the `default` is outside of the `switch` block

Comment: Your approach is actually just like [redux's](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.md#updating-an-item-in-an-array) one. So no further changes on that, unless you want it.

Comment: @mersocarlin why it need item and action.item? that's strange.

Comment: @estherJoo `item` and `action.item`? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: @mersocarlin I mean in redux's doc, the example you shown me

Comment: if you wish to go with a more elegant and readable approach, please see https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state

Comment: @estherJoo not every action is the same. You can model your actions as you wish. Redux example has item on it because it wants to update the entire object in the array. Your case, is more specific and toggles `checked` property only.

Comment: @Theo it's just a library with crud wrapper / api, why everyone is so into immutable.js?

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490574/updating-an-object-within-array-in-react-redux-reducer-getting-map-is-not-a-fu/45490835#45490835. You could also think about using immutableJS for your states if your data is highly nested

Comment: @estherJoo Yes Shubham is right. you might want to use it in very good use cases like updating highly nested states.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do;

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO': {
      let newState = state.concat([]);
      newState.any((item) =>
        item.id == action.id && 
          (item = { ...item, checked: !item.checked })
      ); 

      return newState;
    }
    default:
       return state;
  }
}
```

If you can change the data structure of your todo list to a map, then I think the following looks more readable.

```
const todos = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO': {
      let itemToChange = state[action.id];
      return { 
        ...state, 
        [action.id]: { 
          ...itemToChange, 
          checked: !itemToChange.checked 
        }
      };
    }
    default:
       return state
  }
}
```

Comment: this is slick too, especially the second one using array's index, no need to go through the entire loop.

Comment: In the second approach, the list of todos is actually just a plain object (not an array) mapping id (of the todo item) to the actual item; if this answer helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it :)