# React Native redux reducers best way to push array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following state and reducer but it's not pushing in the new array object.

```
const initialState = {
    photos: [],
    selectedPhoto:{},
    photosTeamId:'',
    photosProjectId:''
};

case actionTypes.PHOTOS_UPDATE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                photos:action.data.photos,
                photosTeamId:action.data.photosTeamId,
                photosProjectId:action.data.photosProjectId
            })
```

photos is not getting pushed but overwritten

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/use-object-assign-or-spread-operator-in-react-redux-which-is-a-better-practise/43376980#43376980 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949387/how-to-use-immutability-helper-to-update-a-nested-object-within-an-array/41949486#41949486. You can either go with Spread operator syntax or Immutability-helper package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more cleaner way using **[javascript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**:

```
const initialState = {
    photos: [],
    selectedPhoto:{},
    photosTeamId:'',
    photosProjectId:''
};

case actionTypes.PHOTOS_UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                photos: [...state.photos, ...actions.data.photos],
                photosTeamId: action.data.photosTeamId,
                photosProjectId: action.data.photosProjectId
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case actionTypes.PHOTOS_UPDATE:
  return {
    ...state,
    photos: state.photos.concat(action.data.photos),
    photosTeamId: action.data.photosTeamId,
    photosProjectId: action.data.photosProjectId
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the spread operator […]. The spread operator can be used to take an existing array and add another element to it while still preserving the original array.

Example:

```js
case actionTypes.PHOTOS_UPDATE:
  return [
    ...state,
    Object.assign({}, {
      photos:action.data.photos,
      photosTeamId:action.data.photosTeamId,
      photosProjectId:action.data.photosProjectId
    })
  ];
```