# React reducer how to update nested object using find by id?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following state

```
const initialState = {
    photos: [],
    selectedPhoto:{},
    photosTeamId:'',
    photosProjectId:''
};
```

photos is an array which has a photo object and inside the photo object, there is an array of comments. I'm trying to find the correct photo then find the correct comment and update that one.

Here is my code

```
case actionTypes.COMMENT_UPDATED_TO_PHOTOS:
            console.log(action.data)
            return {
                ...state,
                photos: state.photos.map((photo) => {
                     photo.id === action.data.selectedPhotoId ? {
                        comments: photo.comments.map((comment) => {
                            console.log(comment)
                            return comment.id === action.data.commentId ? { ...comment, comment: action.data.fullComment } : comment
                        })
                    } : photo
                })
            }
```

Comment: It is not your code . It is an answer on your first question. and here, you built the second question as an aggregation of first question with its answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47068926/747579

Comment: The first question was different use case

Comment: Ah ok got it! Sorry Almog.  @ShubhnikSingh Please your help.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: React reducer how to update nested object using find by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks okay, except for the curly braces around the outer anonymous function. Since these declare a code block, there should be a `return` statement before `photo.is === ...`, or you can simply remove them altogether to get an expression:

```
case actionTypes.COMMENT_UPDATED_TO_PHOTOS:
            console.log(action.data)
            return {
                ...state,
                photos: state.photos.map((photo) =>
                    photo.id === action.data.selectedPhotoId ? {
                        ...photo,
                        comments: photo.comments.map((comment) => {
                            console.log(comment)
                            return comment.id === action.data.commentId ? { ...comment, comment: action.data.fullComment } : comment
                        })
                    } : photo
                )
            }
```

UPDATE: there was also a missing `...photo,`, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to just update the comment data how would I do that here is the comment object 

{createdBy: {…}, comment: "New jjjj ggggg ggg", createdAt: "2017-11-03T02:38:16.828Z", id: "59fbd698e0048b1474207e8f"}
comment
:
"New jjjj ggggg ggg"
createdAt
:
"2017-11-03T02:38:16.828Z"
createdBy
:
{lastName: "Koren", firstName: "Almog", fullName: "Almog Koren", id: "59d4821f3c28f634c99e5abf"}
id
:
"59fbd698e0048b1474207e8f"

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here, as the code you have already seems to do that. You can update other fields by adding them to the resulting object, e.g. `{...comment, comment: .., createdAt: ..}`, or you can put the fields you want to update in another object `updates` and use `{...comment, ...updates}`. There's lots of different ways.

Comment: When I run the update it seems like the other fields are removed, createdAt is gone? Like it's overwriting everything

Comment: This code will preserve all fields in each comment object, so if the other fields are gone, probably something else is wrong. Maybe they are not present in the state? (in which case your `console.log` statement will also not show them)

Comment: So yes it updates and saves all the comments but all the other objects in the photo are gone like uploadedAt which is in the outer photo object

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. There's also an object spread missing. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect