# Write nested objects in this.state in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an object in state in React .What I require us that 'status' is actually a field that is updated by setState

```
 this.state = {
        data:[],
        sort: 0,
        field:"",
        filters:{
            'status':{
                value:""
            }
```

The code should be:

```
this.state = {
        data:[],
        sort: 0,
        field:"",
        filters:{
            field:{
                value:""
            }
```

How should I set the same object to the nested object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
this.setState({filters:{[field]:{value:e}}
```

Comment: Answering questions is good, thank you. But giving an answer that is just code with no explanation is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so..

```
let filters = {
  field:{
    value: ""
  }
};

this.setState({filters});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
this.setState({
  filters: { ...this.state.filters, field: { value: 'new value' },
});
```

However the above syntax is ugly. I recommend you to use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) package to update the state.

See this answer on how to update state with [immutability helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949387/how-to-use-immutability-helper-to-update-a-nested-object-within-an-array/41949486#41949486).

Comment: Note that you may also use the [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) library, which has methods specifically for these cases.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution, I worked with the following code 
      this.setState({
            filters:{
        
               [field]:{
                   value:e
               }
            }

Answer (score 0):

**setState for nested object.**

```
 this.state = {
        data:[],
        sort: 0,
        field:"",
        filters:{
            status:{
                value:""
            }
```

If we want update 'status' using setState method follow this method this may help you.

```
let filters = {...this.state.filters}
filters.status = { value: 10 };
this.setState({filters})
```

Ref this doc: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)