# Best practice to handle data from api in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on one of my first react projects and got this question.

What is the best way to handle and store data in react with using `this.state`?

My current workflow:

1. fetch data from api in `componentDidMount()`
2. storing the data in `this.state` (for example in `this.state.account_data` as child object`
3. using the data in `value` attributes of controls like `<input>` in this way: `this.state.account_data.username`
4. each control has his own `onChange`-handler `onChange={e => this.onChangeUsername(e)}`

The method `onChangeUsername(e)` changes `this.state` with `this.setState({username: e.target.value})`.

So, the problem is: After changing the unsername control value, I have two variants of the username in `this.state`: `this.state.account_data.username` and `this.state.username`. That requires to create another part of code to update `this.state.account_data`, because I want to send the new data to the API by `UserService.update(this.state.account_data)`.

Is there an easier way or what is the best practice?

Comment: Avoid state manipulation directly. User React-Redux instead. Refer [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/) for an introduction.

Comment: Why should I avoid state manipulation directly?

Comment: It becomes tough as the application grows in size. And why not try redux? I'm sure you won't ask that question once the concept hits you. It's far more logical and easier to maintain a single source of truth for the entire application.

Comment: `redux` is good when you have different components sharing the same state and you would like to avoid the necessity of a parent component storing it and passing down the data via `props`, HOC pattern. In a lot of case it may result in overingeering, or unuseful if you go with another state management architecture, for example `Apollo` + `Next` + `Graphql`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html), React suggests to use this library to handle data mutations: [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

The idea is that in your `onChangeUsername(e)` you will copy the original part of state you need to update with `update` function. In this case `const myNewAccountData = update( this.state.account_data, ... )` and then you set the new state with `this.setState({account_data : myNewAccountData })`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949486/12506641) for an example on updating nested object with `immutability-helper`.

And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136076/12506641) you can find an explanation on why to avoid nested object as React state or at least why it may be considered not a best practice.